# Can't start foreground service from background in Android P

Tags: service, alarmmanager, foreground-service, android-9.0-pie

To play a long audio file at a certain time (an alarm), I used AlarmManager.setAlarmClock and started a foreground service at certain time.
The app is in background at time alarm triggers, it's working properly in Android versions prior to P.
But in Android P sometimes service starts and sometimes it doesn't.

(I've included foreground service permission in manifest)

Comment: Without an [mcve], it will be difficult for anyone to help you. You might also check LogCat around the time of the alarm to see if there are any messages of relevance.